# Vb.net -- Reducing an if statement based on checkbox / radio button

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, radio-button

So at present I am learning VB and I have a project in which I have to display a picture box based on:

Which radio box is checked

and

if a checkbox to make the picture box visible is checked.  As someone who values clean, good code this is my code and it horrifies me.   My question, is there some way to condense the following using cases or some other construct I don't know in VB.net?

```
    If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        BooksPictureBox.Visible = False
        MusicPictureBox.Visible = False
        PeriodicalsPictureBox.Visible = False
        CoffeeBarPictureBox.Visible = False
    End If
    If RadioButton1.Checked And CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        BooksPictureBox.Visible = True
        MusicPictureBox.Visible = False
        PeriodicalsPictureBox.Visible = False
        CoffeeBarPictureBox.Visible = False
    End If
    If RadioButton2.Checked And CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        BooksPictureBox.Visible = False
        MusicPictureBox.Visible = True
        PeriodicalsPictureBox.Visible = False
        CoffeeBarPictureBox.Visible = False
    End If
    If RadioButton3.Checked And CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        BooksPictureBox.Visible = False
        MusicPictureBox.Visible = False
        PeriodicalsPictureBox.Visible = True
        CoffeeBarPictureBox.Visible = False
    End If
    If RadioButton4.Checked And CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        BooksPictureBox.Visible = False
        MusicPictureBox.Visible = False
        PeriodicalsPictureBox.Visible = False
        CoffeeBarPictureBox.Visible = True
    End If
```

Note- all the images stack on one another, and all of them start without being visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a SUb that sets all picBoxes to not visible

```
Private Sub setInvisible
   BooksPictureBox.Visible = False
   MusicPictureBox.Visible = False
   PeriodicalsPictureBox.Visible = False
   CoffeeBarPictureBox.Visible = False
End sub
```

Then another routine

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    setInvisible
    if checkbox1.checked = false then exit sub
    if radiobutton1.checked = true then bookspicturebox.visible = true
    if radiobutton2.checked = true then musicpicturebox.visible = true
etc...

End Sub
```

Of course, an easier way would be to just have the image dynamically load based upon radio button selection.

Comment: I don't like `If checked = False Then` or `If checked = True Then`. `If Not checked Then` or `If checked Then` is fully sufficient.

Comment: @ Olivier.  True.  My coding habits spell things out probably more than they need to be.

Comment: Often I see code like `If x > y Then Return True Else Return False End If`. `Return x > y` is all you need.

Comment: @Oliver.  Again, true.  I do use shortened code when it is being used in functionality where no one is going to touch it.  However, I often pass my code off to others to maintain, so I tend to spell everything out so I don't get questions later.  And yes, that is even after commenting what the code is doing.  Even on the "return x > y" statement, if I said "returns true if x is greater than y and false otherwise", I would still get questions about "how" that actually works.  And I would especially use longer code when discussing with a newer VB user.  In hindsight, I should have presented both

Comment: I prefer writing good code and having to explain it, rather than bad one, which even dummies understand.

Comment: What I have posted is not "bad" code.  It is just fully qualified.  Does it work and can it be understood within this context?  I think you are confusing "bad" with "verbose." ;)

Comment: I actually mean bad style code. You don't write `y = x * 1`. You just write `y = x`. `res = checked = True` and `res = checked` is just the same. I suspect that people who write `checked = True` often don't really know how booleans work.

Comment: Sometimes I actually like the " = true" or " = false".  Even in my own code, I have missed the "Not" in front of the boolean during my code reviews and had to go back to verify that it was there.  I immediately see the "= false" and know that is what I am looking for.  As you point out, it "is just the same."  Just because they write it out does not mean that they don't understand how it works.  Personal preference, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
' Set first condition, the check box must be checked
BooksPictureBox.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked
MusicPictureBox.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked
PeriodicalsPictureBox.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked
CoffeeBarPictureBox.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked

' Set individual conditions, the radio button must be checked
BooksPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton1.Checked
MusicPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton2.Checked
PeriodicalsPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton3.Checked
CoffeeBarPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton4.Checked
```

**Edit**: Or, you could take a different [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) approach :)

```
ShowOrHidePictureBoxes()

...

Private Sub ShowOrHidePictureBoxes
  ShowOrHideBooks()
  ShowOrHideMusic()
  ShowOrHidePeriodicals()
  ShowOrHideCoffeeBar()
End Sub

Private Sub ShowOrHideBooks
  BooksPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton1.Checked And CheckBox1.Checked
End Sub

Private Sub ShowOrHideMusic
  BooksPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton2.Checked And CheckBox1.Checked
End Sub

Private Sub ShowOrHidePeriodicals
  BooksPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton3.Checked And CheckBox1.Checked
End Sub

Private Sub ShowOrHideCoffeeBar
  BooksPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton4.Checked And CheckBox1.Checked
End Sub
```

You could take this further in two ways:

1. Extract the logic out into a shared helper class to re-use throughout the application, or even into actual models which represent the business concepts in the application.  This will depend heavily on how the rest of the application is to be designed, what the business needs are, etc.  In the context of this question it's more of a thought exercise than a real answer.
2. Name your controls better so that the code looks more expressive.  Things like `CheckBox1` and `RadioButton1` pollute the code more than the `If` statements did :)

Answer (score 0):

You could get it down to something like:

```
    Dim fBooksVisible As Boolean
    Dim fMusicVisible As Boolean
    Dim fPeriodicalsVisible As Boolean
    Dim fCoffeeBarVisible As Boolean

    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        fBooksVisible = RadioButton1.Checked
        fMusicVisible = RadioButton2.Checked
        fPeriodicalsVisible = RadioButton3.Checked
        fCoffeeBarVisible = RadioButton4.Checked
    End If

    BooksPictureBox.Visible = fBooksVisible
    MusicPictureBox.Visible = fMusicVisible
    PeriodicalsPictureBox.Visible = fPeriodicalsVisible
    CoffeeBarPictureBox.Visible = fCoffeeBarVisible
```

or even:

```
    BooksPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton1.Checked AndAlso CheckBox1.Checked
    MusicPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton2.Checked AndAlso CheckBox1.Checked
    PeriodicalsPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton3.Checked AndAlso CheckBox1.Checked
    CoffeeBarPictureBox.Visible = RadioButton4.Checked AndAlso CheckBox1.Checked
```